# jquery add event to cells into a board

Tags: javascript, jquery, cells, focusout

How can I add an event to cells inside a board?
I have a grid of 9x9 and I want to add an event to them, for example, this is part of my grid in HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dad-board">
      <div class="dad-row">
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="0" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="1" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="2" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="3" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="4" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="5" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="6" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="7" data-line="0">
        </div>
        <div class="dad-cell">
            <input type="number"  data-column="8" data-line="0">
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now in jquery I wanted to do something like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'


    $('#dad-board > dad-cell').focusout(function(){

        if($(this).text()>0 && $(this).text()<10){

            $(this).addClass('with-value');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('with-value');
        }

    });
}());
```

Comment: Little error  $('#dad-board > `.`dad-cell'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

In `$('#dad-board > dad-cell')` the class name should be `.dad-cell`.

`.dad-cell` are `div` and as such them don't have a `focusout` event. I think you meant `$('#dad-board > .dad-cell input')`.

In order to make your current code work, you'll also have to make some adjustments:

```
$('#dad-board > .dad-cell input').focusout(function(){
    //as we're talking about input fields, the value is read with val(), not text()
    //and as you're gonna evaluate it as an integer, lets convert the value to integer
    var value=parseInt($(this).val());       
    if(!isNaN(value)&&value>0 && value<10){
        //you might want to set with-value to the <div>, not the input
        $(this).parent().addClass('with-value');
    }else{
        //you might want to set with-value to the <div>, not the input
        $(this).parent().removeClass('with-value');
    }
});
```

Comment: I see, so I should put $('#dad-board > .dad-cell input') and then I can use the focusout event?

Comment: Sort of.. With `$('#dad-board > .dad-cell input')` you're listening to the inputs' focus out, that's what you need. But you will also need to make a little adjustment to the code in order to make it work. I'll ellaborate in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('#dad-board > dad-cell')` selector is error,
it should be  `$('.dad-board >.dad-row> .dad-cell')`.

The class should be `.` not `#`.

`A > E` only  select the first child.

> Any E element that is a child (i.e. direct descendant) of an A element

`A E` can select all descendant, like `$('.dad-board  .dad-cell')`

> Any E element that is a descendant of an A element (that is: a child, or a child of a child, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for explain me how it works... I'm new in js and jquery so I don't know much about it... it's much more diferent than java... Thank you very much